# Puppet: How can I wrap a command into two line if >80 characters?

Tags: coding-style, puppet

In puppet, if define command is > 80 characters, how can I wrap into two line to do it?

```
  exec { 'create_domain':
    command => "some command exceed 80 character...........................................................how to do how to do?.......",
  }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's sort of ugly, but if the last character in a string is a `\` followed by a newline, then the string is continued on the next line.  My `sample.pp` manifest is below:

```
exec { 'wrapped_string_example':
  command => "/bin/echo 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890\
wrapped > /var/tmp/test.txt";
}
```

Running this with `puppet apply sample.pp` gives the following output

```
$ puppet apply sample.pp
notice: /Stage[main]/Exec[wrapped_string_example]/returns: executed successfully
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.10 seconds
```

And catting the created file shows the lines have wrapped:

```
$ cat /var/tmp/test.txt 
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890wrapped
```

See https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/9fbb36de/lib/puppet/parser/lexer.rb#L537 (as of Puppet v2.7.0)

Also this is sort of a known issue: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/5022

Comment: gvim only with ruby syntax highlight

Comment: If spaces in the middle of the command don't matter then you can still indent the next line to the "correct" column in the continued command after the backslash...

Comment: Not really an answer to the question, but you can alternatively ignore the puppet-lint complaints locally using `# lint:ignore:140chars`, as described at http://puppet-lint.com/controlcomments/

Answer (score 8):

For big chunks of data, heredocs are the best way of dealing with long lines in Puppet manifests. The `/L` interpolation option is particularly useful. `/L` causes `\` at the end of a line to remove newlines. For example, the following does what you'd expect, stripping indentation and newlines, including the trailing newline.

```
  sshkey { 'example.com':
    ensure  => present,
    type    => 'ssh-rsa',
    key     => @(KEY/L),
      RfrXBrU1T6qMNllnhXsJdaud9yBgWWm6OprdEQ3rpkTvCc9kJKH0k8MNfKxeBiGZVsUn435q\
      e83opnamtGBz17gUOrzjfmpRuBaDDGmGGTPcO8Dohwz1zYuir93bJmxkNldjogbjAWPfrX10\
      8aoDw26K12sK61lOt6GTdR9yjDPdG4zL5G3ZjXCuDyQ6mzcNHdAPPFRQdlRRyCtG2sQWpWan\
      3AlYe6h6bG48thlo6vyNvOD8s9K0YBnwl596DJiNCY6EsxnSAhA3Uf9jeKqlVqqrxhEzHufx\
      07iP1nXIXCMUV
      |-KEY
    target  => '/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys',
  }
```

Or to keep the final newline, leave out the `-` before the end text:

```
exec { 'create_domain':
  command => @(CMD/L),
    /bin/echo 123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456\
    wrapped > /var/tmp/test.txt
    | CMD
}
```

Comment: Is the comma after @(KEY/L) a typo?

Comment: @Flo No, the comma isn't a typo. It looks weird, but is needed because of the way the parser treats heredocs.

Answer (score 7):

As of Puppet 3.5 you have a couple of options that i have used.  Ruby allows you to concat strings over a couple of lines.

```
string = "line #1"\
         "line #2"\
         "line #3"

p string # => "line #1line #2line #3"
```

Another option, as of Puppet 3.5 they have added HereDoc functionality.  This will allow you to put the string in a section of a source code file that is treated as if it were a separate file.

```
$mytext = @(EOT)
    This block of text is
    visibly separated from
    everything around it.
    | EOT
```

The puppet documentation is here: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.9/lang_data_string.html#heredocs

Comment: Bear in mind that the HereDoc sample you provided keeps the line breaks. The question is asking about splitting a command that belongs on one line over several lines in manifest.

Answer (score 5):

If you really care about the 80cols limit you can always abuse a template to achieve that goal

```
exec {'VeryLongExec':
    command => template("${module}/verylongexec")
 }
```

Then put the actual command in that template file

Credits should go to Jan Vansteenkiste to figure

Comment: Actually you need to use `$module_name` and not `$module` (at least for Puppet 3.7).