# How do i append some string to existing line( not the end of file ) in file in puppet?

Tags: puppet

Original file

```
# cat testfile
one
two
three 
four
```

Changes needed on the file

```
# cat testfile
one
two
three mynum <-- string is added here
four
```

I came across file_line module which helps in appending to the end of the file.I could not find any pointers which matches my need to append to the existing line.

Is there anything to regex the string "three" and append to the same line?  or any other alternatives.

Comment: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/reference#match

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the `match` option to `file_line` for this.

Try

```
file_line { 'add mynum to line starting with three':
  path   => '/fullpath/testfile',
  line   => 'three mynum',
  match  => '^three ',
}
```

The `match` option is documented at https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib/reference#match.

You can factor the pattern out into a variable if needed:

```
$line_pattern = 'three'

file_line { 'add mynum to line starting with three':
  path   => '/fullpath/testfile',
  line   => "${line_pattern} mynum",
  match  => "^${line_pattern} ",
}
```

Comment: Line "three" is just a place holder on that line. Line can be very big indeed. "Mynum" must be appended at the end of line.

Comment: That's fine. The string `three` can be factored out into a variable, and Puppet can handle long lines https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406234/puppet-how-can-i-wrap-a-command-into-two-line-if-80-characters

Comment: im looking for variable placeholder, is that possible?  e.g.so i can PREPEND the line? `line   => '$1 three mynum'`